# Hana Clould TypeORM insufficient privilege

Tags: nodes, typeorm, nest, hana

Missing privilege error after executing the steps below:

1. File `ormconfig.ts`:

   [image: ormconfig.ts]
2. File `package.json`:

   ```json
   { "typeorm:cli": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -f ./ormconfig.ts"`
   ```
3. run: `npm run typeorm:cli --migration`
   [image]
4. error in database Hana cloud
   [image]

Is there a way to disable the schema change or set this permission via code, with the user present in `default-env`?

Note: inside the `/db` folder when executing npm start (standard process) it generates as tables in the database. This error only occurs with typeorm.

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the database user name you seem to be using an HDI container for your application. HDI is a way of managing the lifecycle of database objects, just like the TypeORM migrations. Using both HDI and TypeORM to manage the lifecycle of database objects can lead to inconsistencies which is why HDI restricts the permissions on its schemas. That's why you're seeing the insufficient privilege error.

If you want to use TypeORM migrations you should use a schema plan instead of an HDI container. The schema plan will give you full control over the schema. This should allow the TypeORM migrations to run successfully.